# Prime numbers of the form : $2^{n+a}+2^{n} \pm 1$ , where $0 \leq a < n$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that :

> For any positive integer $n$ such that $n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ there is at least one prime number of the form:
>
> $p=2^{n+a}+2^{n} + 1$  , or ,  $p=2^{n+a}+2^{n} - 1$
>
> with following properties : $0 \leq a < n$  , and $a\in \mathbf{Z^{*}} ; n\in \mathbf{Z^{+}} $

I have checked statement for each $n$ up to $n=1002$ and I haven't found any counterexample.

Any idea how to prove or disprove statement above without using a computer?

Comment: IOW, OTF $64^m(2^a+1)\pm1,m\in\mathbb{N},0\le a<6m$.

Comment: [related sequence](http://oeis.org/A126717)

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture appears to be false for $n=2184$.